# Ignore error from the preivous build task in tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I configured `tasks.json` to build and run the application.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make"
        },
        {
            "label": "close the file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "somecommand"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run build",
            "dependsOn": [
                "build",
                "close the file"
            ],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The flow is first `make` command will execute and after that `somecommand` will be executed. The problem is some times `make` command returns exit code other than zero, Because of that `somecommand` is not executing. Is there any way to ignore the previous build status and execute the `somecommand` always?

Comment: write a shell script and run that with a task

Comment: @rioV8, ya I am doing that now.But is there any other alternative to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore error code in task of type `shell`, simply add some nop command at the end using [`||` operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190546). Valid for both bash and batch.

Like:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make || echo 0"
        },
        {
            "label": "close the file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "somecommand"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run build",
            "dependsOn": [
                "build",
                "close the file"
            ],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This ignores the error in the shell, not the task.

Comment: @Paul right, answer fixed

Comment: be aware that "args" would applied to the last part of the command. In case some args are required those sould be part of the command

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `..."||", "echo", "0"],` to the end of `args` for the same effect, if arguments are convenient/ required for your task.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a simple Power Shell:

```
-ErrorAction Ignore
```

Does the job, but it depends on what you're doing.
[Here's the reference for the shell](https://ss64.com/ps/common.html).